# While rendering displaying Loading Icon doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, performance

```
 <div ng-if="!loading">
    //some code
    </div>
    <div ng-if="loading">
    <loading></loading>
    </div>

    angular.module('indexApp.directives')
    .directive('loading', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="../../../cim/images/projIcons/loading.gif" width="250px" height="45px" /></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                if (val)
                    $(element).show();
                else
                    $(element).hide();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This code work well as expected showing loading while data is less.In js written code for loading variable for making it true and false when data gets received. As soon as data is more loading icon is not showing. After some check found that, loading icon can be showed only when data is not received from back-end.

Once data is received loading icon gets removed. So in larger data case, time taken was for rendering. So for rendering it is not showing loading icon. Is it any mechanism by which we keep loading icon till browser complete data rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Actually this code worked fine for me.

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');

            var spinnerFunction = function spinnerFunction(data, headersGetter) {
                $(".loader").show();
                return data;
            };

            $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
        });

        //Defining Factory 
        app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $window) {

            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(function (response) {
                    $(".loader").hide();
                    return response;
                }, function (response) {
                    $(".loader").hide();
                    return $q.reject(response);
                });
            };
        });
```

Comment: it doesnt worked in my case. Im checking for more specific to angular.

Comment: Ok , Will look into it and will let you know if i can found other ways.